# ViewPager not refreshing after refresh call is made

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, retrofit

I'm developing a weather forecast app using OpenWeatherMap API, all goes smooth and nice unless the refresh of the app when the user is trying to fetch data for another city, I've tested the server call and it returns true data, the one that should be refreshed but the view is not updated in the fragments.

This is segment from MainActivity class:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements
            NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        session = new SessionManagement(MainActivity.this);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        //Initializes the components that the MainActivity layout has
        city = getResources().getString(R.string.default_city);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View navigationViewHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        mHeaderCityName = (TextView) navigationViewHeader.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_city);
        mHeaderCityTemp = (TextView) navigationViewHeader.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_city_temp);
        mFavCities = (ListView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.lv_favorite_cities);
        mTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl_tabs);
        mPages = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_view_pager);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        adapter = new MeteoPlusPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mPages);
        savedCities = new ArrayList<>();
        favoriteCities = new ArrayList<>();
        citiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, favoriteCities);
        mFavCities.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
        if (session.getFavorites() != null) {
            savedCities = new ArrayList<>(session.getFavorites());

            if (savedCities.size() > 0) {
                favoriteCities.addAll(savedCities);
                citiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                TextView mNoFavs = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_favorites);
                mNoFavs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mFavCities.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        fetchWeatherData((String) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        if (citiesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            TextView mNoFavs = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_favorites);
            mNoFavs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mFavCities.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mFavCities.setEmptyView(navigationView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_favorites));
        }

    }

    /**
     * Fetches data for weather preferences from server
     *
     * @param city
     */
    void fetchWeatherData(final String city) {
        final ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        String appId = getResources().getString(R.string.openweathermap_appid);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call = apiService.getCurrentWeatherDataSingleLocation(city, appId);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data. Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                weatherResponse = response.body();
                mHeaderCityName.setText(city);
                Log.d("city",weatherResponse.getCityName());//after refresh correct data returned
                Log.d("cityId",Integer.toString(weatherResponse.getId()));//after refresh correct data returned
                String identifier = isFahrenheit ? "°F" : "°C";
                String temperature = String.format("%.0f " + identifier,
                        MeteoPlusUtility.convert(weatherResponse.getMain().getTemperature(), isFahrenheit));
                mHeaderCityTemp.setText(temperature);
                if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                setupViewPager(mPages, weatherResponse);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(weatherResponse.getCityName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                call.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to obtain results!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call.cancel();
                // Log.e("API_CALL", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param viewPager the actual viewpager of the activity
     */
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, WeatherResponse weatherResponse) {
        //Sets up the whole view pager with all the pages in it
        if (weatherResponse != null) {
            String city = weatherResponse.getCityName();
            String id = String.valueOf(weatherResponse.getId());
            adapter.addFragment(NowFragment.newInstance(city), "Now");
            adapter.addFragment(FiveDayThreeHourFragment.newInstance(id), "5 day/3 hour");
            adapter.addFragment(DailyFragment.newInstance(id, "16"), "Daily");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    private void displayAnotherCity() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Select city");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please enter city");

        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(input);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        fetchWeatherData(input.getText().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

And this is a segment of NowFragment, all fragment populate and fetch data in the same way in onActivityCreated method.

```
  @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mNow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_now, container, false);

        initComponents(mNow);
        return mNow;
    }

    /**
     * fetches data from server and populates the view
     *
     * @param city
     */
    void fetchWeatherData(String city) {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        String appId = getResources().getString(R.string.openweathermap_appid);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call = apiService.getCurrentWeatherDataSingleLocation(city, appId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                weatherData = response.body();
                prepareData(weatherData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to obtain results!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("API_CALL", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Intitializes the elements of the view
     *
     * @param view the view to display
     */
    private void initComponents(View view) {
        city = getArguments().getString(MeteoPlusUtility.TAG_CURRENT_WEATHER);
        mCurrenTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_time);
        mWeatherTemperature = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_temperature);
        mWeatherMain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_main);
        mWeatherDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_description);
        mWeatherHumidity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_humidity);
        mWeatherWindSpeed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_wind_speed);
        mWeatherPressure = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_pressure);
        mWeatherHighTemp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_high_temp);
        mWeatherLowTemp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_low_temp);
        mWeatherSunrise = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_sunrise);
        mWeatherSunset = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_sunset);
        mWeatherDataCalculation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_dt);
        mWeatherIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_weather_icon);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        refreshData();
    }


    /**
     * prepares all the data fetched from server to the corresponding elements in the layout
     *
     * @param wData response from server
     */
    private void prepareData(WeatherResponse wData) {
        if (wData != null) {
            MainWeatherData mainWeatherData = wData.getMain();
            List<Weather> wList = wData.getWeatherList();
            Weather generalWeatherData = wList.get(0);
            Wind wind = wData.getWind();
            WeatherSystem sys = wData.getSys();
            String identifier = isFahrenheit ? "°F" : "°C";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(MeteoPlusUtility.OPENWEATHER_ICON_URL + generalWeatherData.getIconId() + ".png");
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri).resize(300, 300).centerInside().into(mWeatherIcon);
            mCurrenTime.setText(MeteoPlusUtility.currentDateToString());
            String temperature = String.format("%.0f " + identifier, MeteoPlusUtility.convert(mainWeatherData.getTemperature(), isFahrenheit));
            mWeatherTemperature.setText(temperature);
            mWeatherMain.setText(generalWeatherData.getMain());
            mWeatherDescription.setText(generalWeatherData.getDescription());
            String humidity = String.valueOf(mainWeatherData.getHumidity()) + " %";
            mWeatherHumidity.setText(humidity);
            String windSpeed = String.valueOf(wind.getSpeed()) + " KPH";
            mWeatherWindSpeed.setText(windSpeed);
            String pressure = String.valueOf(mainWeatherData.getPressure()) + " hPa";
            mWeatherPressure.setText(pressure);
            String lowTemp = String.format("%.0f " + identifier, MeteoPlusUtility.convert(mainWeatherData.getTempMin(), isFahrenheit));
            mWeatherLowTemp.setText(lowTemp);
            String highTemp = String.format("%.0f " + identifier, MeteoPlusUtility.convert(mainWeatherData.getTempMax(), isFahrenheit));
            mWeatherHighTemp.setText(highTemp);
            mWeatherSunrise.setText(MeteoPlusUtility.getTimeInPreetyFormat(sys.getSunrise(),
                    new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm zzz")));
            mWeatherSunset.setText(MeteoPlusUtility.getTimeInPreetyFormat(sys.getSunset(),
                    new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm zzz")));
            mWeatherDataCalculation.setText(MeteoPlusUtility.getTimeInPreetyFormat(wData.getTimeofDataCalculation(), new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm zzz")));
        }
    }


    /**
     * creates instance of the fragment
     *
     * @param city used for data fetch
     * @return fragment
     */
    public static NowFragment newInstance(String city) {
        NowFragment nowFragment = new NowFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(MeteoPlusUtility.TAG_CURRENT_WEATHER, city);
        nowFragment.setArguments(args);

        return nowFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshData() {
        fetchWeatherData(city);
    }
```

This is the ViewPagerAdapter code:

```
 public class MeteoPlusPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentsTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public MeteoPlusPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    /**
     * adds fragment and title for the fragment to the corresponding lists
     *
     * @param fragment Fragment to be added
     * @param title    title of the added fragment
     */
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        //Adds fragment to the view pager with title to be displayed in the tab layout
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentsTitles.add(title);
    }
    public void clear(){
        mFragments.clear();
        mFragmentsTitles.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
//        if (object instanceof NowFragment) {
//            ((NowFragment) object).refreshData();
//        } else if (object instanceof FiveDayThreeHourFragment) {
//            ((FiveDayThreeHourFragment) object).refreshData();
//        } else if (object instanceof DailyFragment) {
//            ((DailyFragment) object).refreshData();
//        }
//        return super.getItemPosition(object);
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentsTitles.get(position);
    }
```

I'm really annoyed by this and cannot find the cause of the problem, I debugged and inspected in details, searched for solutions but no results, please help.

Comment: You want to clear all old fragments of `ViewPager` and add new fragments everytime `fetchWeatherData()` get called?

Comment: @nhoxbypass I added the code for clearing the adapter because it duplicates the fragments in the viewpager, and I don't want that, duplicated fragments have correct data, but I don't want duplicate fragments in the viewpager, just existing fragments updated, so I had to do a workaround to remove the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
        return POSITION_NONE;
```

you have to call notifyDataSetChanged for your adapter